# Java class generic class references

Tags: java, generics

I have this abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractA<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    protected T value;
}
```

and my class

```
public class A<T> extends AbstractA {
}
```

I want to use the `compareTo` function in class a

But java gives me the error:

> The method compareTo(capture#5-of ? super capture#4-of ?) in the type Comparable is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable)

the function looks like:

```
protected find(Comparable value){
    if( this.value.compareto(value) == 0){
    //
    }
}
```

But the function should be Called with (T value)

How do I have to extend the abstract class?

Comment: As a point of style, in Java, class names (and interface names) should begin with a capital letter. Variables start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Do you want class `A` still be bound to generic type `T` or a concrete type?

Comment: Please share the code you're invoking `compareTo` with. It's hard to answer a question about an error if you don't show the actual lines of code causing the error.

Comment: You're probably looking for `class A extends AbstractA<A>`.

Comment: @tsolakp Yes I want A still bound to T

Answer (score 0):

To extend it you need to specify a generic interface that implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). For example:

```
public class A<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends AbstractA<T> {
    // ...
}
```

Or a concrete class:

```
public class A extends AbstractA<String> {
    // ...
}
```

`AbstractA` does not *implement* `Comparable`. If you want `A` to implement `Comparable` you need to add it as an `implements` clause. E.g.

```
public class A extends AbstractA<String> implements Comparable<String> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(String arg0) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

To understand generics, there is [a good Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).